# Fill values in certain rows based on conditions

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am working with `sqlite3` in order to integrate with an SQLite database using Python.

I have a single table called `trips`. In it, I have 4 columns:

- `trip_id` (INT primary key values: 1,2,3...2145)
- `day` (TEXT values: '1','2'...'7' )
- `month` (TEXT values: '1','2','3'...'12')
- `is_date`   (vlues: all NULL)

I also have a list of trip ID values.

For each row where the `trip_id` is inside the list I have, I would like to fill the value '1' in the column `is_date` if the day is 3 and month is 1. Else, I would like to fill 0. 
Is there a way to do this with a single SQLite command?

Comment: How would you do that directly in sql?

Comment: Please share your schema.

Comment: no idea, that why im asking here

Comment: what do you mean by schema?

Comment: Schema are the table creation statements. Also, data example would help.

Comment: It sounds like an "update" command in `sql`. But what do you currentaly have in `is_date` column?

Comment: apdated the question to reflact data in each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for the [`CASE`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/)-statement:

```
UPDATE trips 
    SET is_date=CASE WHEN day=3 AND month=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE trip_id IN (1, 2, 3);
```